# Can I safely convert my disk to GPT using diskpart with GRUB 2 installed?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, gpt, grub2

I am wondering whether I would be able to convert my disk 0 (with my system partition, Windows partition, and Ubuntu partitions) from an MBR to GPT disk without loss of data and still being able to boot as I usually do. I have GRUB 2 bootloader installed and worry that GRUB will not be able to load after the conversion. Are my fears unfounded?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that conversion with `diskpart` and retain your data. You can do the conversion with `gdisk` (included with Ubuntu) and retain your on-partition data, but neither OS will be bootable after you complete the conversion. You can restore both OSes to bootability, but it's a bit of a hassle.

Why do you want to do this conversion? The most compelling reason for this is if the "disk" is in fact a RAID array and you've increased its size above the 2TiB limit that MBR can handle. In that case, it may be worth the hassle of re-installing boot loaders. In [another recent question,](https://superuser.com/questions/932579/how-to-recover-data-after-doing-diskpart-clean) somebody went ahead with such a conversion in the belief that it was necessary to install Windows 10. It's not; Windows 10 can install in either BIOS mode (which requires MBR) or EFI mode (which requires GPT). The trouble is getting the boot mode of the installation medium to match what you're using for your hard-disk-based boots. The key is usually the built-in boot manager, which should show two options for booting from an external medium, one of which includes the string "UEFI" and the other of which doesn't. Use the one *without* the "UEFI" string to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. In some cases, tools to create bootable disks omit one boot loader or another, too, which means you've got to find the right option or switch to another tool.

Comment: I don't have a RAID array with more than 2TiB but I wanted to add more partitions so I went through with it using `gdisk` and `gparted`. I managed to use boot-repair through a Live DVD to get GRUB loading again but I can't boot Windows yet. I'm working on that. I think the issue is that GRUB is booting the OSs in BIOS mode but Windows (after having to use the repair disk) thinks it must boot with EFI. Any advice?

Comment: You definitely don't want to mix boot modes; both OSes should boot in the same mode (BIOS or EFI). I used to have a link to a site that explained how to convert Windows from BIOS-mode to EFI-mode booting, but that link has gone dead, and I don't know of another. Maybe Googling will turn something up. Note also that most computers sold before mid-2011 (and some sold after then) don't support EFI, so you might have no choice but to boot in BIOS mode. In that case, you should convert back to MBR, create an extended partition, and add more logical partitions to meet your needs.

Comment: I think you may misunderstand. I don't need to convert Windows 7 to EFI but rather to BIOS/Legacy. I think the issue is that GRUB is trying to boot the OSs as BIOS but Windows is trying to boot through EFI.

Comment: No, I don't believe I've misunderstood. Windows ties its boot mode to the partition table type: If the partition table is MBR, Windows will boot *only* in BIOS mode; and if it's GPT, Windows will boot *only* in EFI mode. Thus, when you did an MBR-to-GPT conversion, you also *required of yourself* a conversion of Windows to boot in EFI mode. Linux is not so constrained; it can boot from a GPT disk in BIOS mode. This complication is one of the reasons I discouraged such a conversion in my original answer. Honestly, switching back to MBR may be the simplest course at this point.

Comment: All right. I'll see what I can do with converting it back. I might just copy my C: drive over to another drive and wait until Windows 10 comes out at which point I'll switch over, removing Ubuntu and GRUB. I don't really "need" Ubuntu. I just thought it could be useful.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question of why you want to do this. You can add more partitions in MBR; they just have to be logical partitions. (If you've got four primary partitions, you'll need to jump through some hoops, but even that's manageable.)